# How to debug composer post update commands

Tags: debugging, command-line, xdebug, composer-php

I have a composer packege which i want to modify, it is part of Laravel framework, but i want to modify it big time. For that i need the xdebug to be able to run via the composer.

To be precise it runs on composer post update hook and there is a error in it.. i can not get it to work, but cant debug it. Anyone has any idea how i can do it?

I tried to do it via command line to test it, but i don`t get any meaningful answers. And i dont know how to run composer command in browser where i have a xdebug command active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can very easily get Xdebug remote debugging on the command line as well. No need for a browser. You simply do:

```
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=sangoku"
```

and then run the composer script. As long as you have xdebug.remote_enable set to 1 in php.ini, this will initiate a debugging request to an open IDE. Depending on your IDE, you might need to do something special though to allow this connection to come in.

Comment: Regrettably, this doesn't work because soon after the beginning of composer, it does a `$xdebug = new XDebugHandler(); $xdebug->check()`, which in turn calls `$this->restart($command)`, which then does a `passthru` of the original command, which is then not caught by XDebug.

Comment: Completing my previous answer: adding COMPOSER_ALLOW_XDEBUG=true to the environment allows the debug to proceed, because the XDebugHandler checks for this variable to decide whether to restart or not.